# Deployment of artifacts to Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, deployment, build

Is there any pattern how to deploy applications (jar-files) to an Hadoop-Custer ? I am not talking about map-reduce jobs but to deploy applications for Spark, Flume etc.

Within the Hadoop ecosystem deployment alone is not sufficient. You need to restart services, deploy configurations (e.g. via Ambari) and so forth.

I have not found any specific tools. Is my assumption correct that you use standard automation tools like maven/jenkins and do the missing parts by yourself ?

Just wondering if I have overseen something. Just do not want to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are managing the Hadoop ecosystem you can use Ambari and Cloudera's manager.  But you will need to stop and restart their services for configuration and library changes.  If the ecosystem is managed outside of this then you have the option of managing the jars with outside tools like Puppet and Salt.  Currently, we use Salt because of the push/pull abilities.

If you are talking about applications, like jobs running on Spark, you will just provide the Hadoop URL in the file path.  For example:
 spark-submit --class my.dev.org.SparkDriver --properties-file mySparkProps.conf wordcount-shaded.jar hdfs://servername/input/file/sample.txt hdfs://servername/output/sparkresults

For applications have dependencies on third party jar files.  Then you do have the option of shading the job's jar file to prevent other application libraries from interfering with each other.  The down side is the application jar file will get big.  I use maven, so I added the maven-shade-plugin artifact and use the default scope (compile) for the dependencies.

Comment: thx. But how can you deploy jars with Ambari ? For instance for flume I do not see the option to deploy custom Flume sinks....only the configuration can be deployed via Ambari

Comment: oh, are you talking about Flume specifically or another one of the components in the ecosystem?  I think you can change the jars throught the Flume master.  Each component in the ecosystem can also be configured in their respective xx-env.sh scripts or through their UIs like Hue.  I sort to toggle between the two of them depending on what I need to change.  Typically, I use Ambari and Cloudera managers to deploy, upgrade, and other system level things.  But for management of each component, I use their respective UIs or scripts.